# Offsetting paths in FabricJS

Tags: fabricjs, offset, stroke

I am using FabricJS's Path feature to draw a complex closed shape - it is a schematic of a rectangular window with arc top. To draw such a window I basically have to draw several versions of the shape, one offset inside the other.
If this was a regular rectangle, I could easily draw several independent rectangles. However, since this is more complex, I would like to draw the outline, and then make a copy and inset it by thickness of my frame. What i need is NOT scaling, but more like offset stroking or stroking with border drawn only on one side of the stroking path.

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: i think it would be easier if you make a path made of 2 disconnected segments with a vector tool, rather than trying to leverage a double stroke.

Comment: also adding a screenshot pf the schematic would help

Comment: Path offsetting is a feature currently in development for the PaperJS library. Hope this helps: https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/371

Comment: Here's example of what I am trying to draw. The inner shape is drawn through doing some bad math (and it doesn't look exactly right). I instead want to draw the inner shape as offset of outer shape.  https://imgur.com/a/WBMOPQ7